# EMF on moving bar when it is shielded from magnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, education, electromagnetic-induction

[image: Fig. 1.: Conductive bar moving along a conductive rail. The bar is shielded from magnetic induction by a highly permeable, insulated cylinder.]

Fig.: Conductive bar moving along a conductive rail. The bar is
shielded from magnetic induction by a highly permeable, insulated cylinder.

I know if a conductive bar moves on a conductive rail
with velocity v through a constant magnetic field B then the
induced voltage is $vlB$.
($v,l,B$ are perpendicular each other, and the length of bar denoted by $l$)
This phenomena generally explained by $F=(q v\times B)$ Lorentz force on a moving charge in field B.

But how could I understand that the induced EMF will be same $(vlB)$ even if the
bar is shielded from magnetic induction by a highly permeable, insulated cylinder.
Inside the cylinder there is only a few percent of $B$ since $μ_r$ is large.

I tried to understand it from this paper:
*A Note on Faraday Paradoxes*
IEEE Transactions on Magnetics, vol. 50, no. 2, February 2014
[tmp.link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FWU0otu-Tx5n06sMQkdYnxIVVpLiX893/view?usp=sharing) helps in fast access for the above paper.

They are using the "modified" Stoke's low because there is discontinuity
of $B$ on surfaces at the inner and outer diameters of the permeable cylinder.
In this paper the reference for this phenomena unfortunately in German language.

Can anybody give me a more detailed explanation and/or title of book for this and like this induction phenomena?
And what can I know from electron distribution in the moving bar (both shielded or unshielded case) if we didn't close the circuit externally with the voltmeter ?